# Best way to shift a list in Python?

Tags: list, shift

I have a list of numbers, let's say :

```
my_list = [2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 1]
```

From this list, I want to obtain a new list. This list would start with the maximum value until the end, and I want the first part (from the beginning until just before the maximum) to be added, like this :

```
my_new_list = [8, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

(basically it corresponds to a horizontal graph shift...)

Is there a simple way to do so ? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apply as many as you want,

To the left:

```
my_list.append(my_list.pop(0))
```

To the right:

```
my_list.insert(0, my_list.pop())
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
max_idx = my_list.index(max(my_list))
my_new_list = my_list[max_idx:] + my_list[0:max_idx]
```

Comment: You can omit the start index when it's 0: `fruits[3:] + fruits[:3]`. If you want a shift of 3, use `len(fruits)-3` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do something like the following,

```
def shift(l,n):
    return itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(l),n,n+len(l))

my_list = [2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 1]
list(shift(my_list, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Yasc's solution for moving the order of the list values, here's a way to shift the list to start with the maximum value:

```
# Find the max value:

max_value = max(my_list)

# Move the last value from the end to the beginning, 
# until the max value is the first value:

while my_list[0] != max_value:
    my_list.insert(0, my_list.pop())
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!