# How to circularly shift a vector by n in python

Tags: python

I am trying to circularly shift a vector.
I have tried using np.roll, but I can't get the vector to rotate by more than one row.

Here's an example:
I want to rearrange the vector [1 2 3 4 5] as the following:
First, rotate one shift at a time:

```
[2 3 4 5 1]
[3 4 5 1 2]
[4 5 1 2 3]
[5 1 2 3 4]
```

Now we are back the original [1 2 3 4 5], so next we rotate every two shifts:

```
[1 3 5 2 4]
```

Now we are back to the original [1 3 5 2 4], so next we add 1 and rotate every 3 shifts:

```
[2 5 3 1 4]
```

Now we are back to where we started at [2 5 3 14], so next we add 1 and rotate every 4 shifts:

```
[3 2 1 5 4]
```

Now we are back to where we started at [3 2 1 5 4], so next we add 1 and rotate every 5 shifts:

```
[4 3 2 1 5]
```

Now we are back to where we started at [4 3 2 1 5], so next we add 1 and rotate every 6 shifts:

```
[5 4 3 2 1]
```

Now I want to stop after I rotate 5 + 1 shifts, or 6 shifts.

Are there any functions that could help with this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146307/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-push-and-pop-a-list-in-python answer your question?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501591/ddg#44501881

Comment: This works great, thanks Malcom!!